# How to modify static file content with express.static?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using `express.static` to serve some static files. I want to modify some files content before return to the client. Below is the source code for static resources under `/public` path.

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

There are some `html` files under the public directory and I want to modify the html files before responsing to the client.

How can I do that with `static`? I know I can add customized middlewares but not sure how. Is there a middleware pattern I can use?

Answer (score 6):

You don't use `express.static()` for files you want to modify - that's not what it does.

Instead, you create routes for the specific URLs you want to do modification on, then you read the file from disk, make your modification and send it back to the client.  There are dozens of template systems for the Express eco-system (such as EJS, Jade, Handlebars, etc...) that are specifically designed to solve this problem.  Or, if you really want to write your own, you can just load the file yourself, make whatever modifications you want and then send it.

```
app.get("/public/somefile", function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'somefile'), function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.sendStatus(404);
        } else {
            // modify the data here, then send it
            res.send(data);
        }
    });
});

// put express.static after your other routes that serve from the public
// directory so those other routes are matched first
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```